# Ender 3 Extruder Speed / Upgrade

Tags: creality-ender-3, extruder, speed, bowden

I am attempting to make my Ender 3 Pro print significantly faster than it is intended it I fear.

I hear a clicking noise coming from the extruder above 130 mm/s in Cura when it is going in long straight lines (I think my acceleration settings prevent it on shorter lines).  I have seen this before when the bed is too close to the nozzle but I have auto bed leveling now and it is happening on all layers.

I have a standard extruder + Bowden tube setup.  What can I do to make things go faster?  I am less concerned about the quality of the print and more concerned about the speed.

[image: Front View]

[image: Top View]

Comment: Try a larger nozzle

Comment: Not an option for the parts I am making, did consider it.

Comment: Have you increased the extruder current? you risk grinding the filament, but if you also increase the spring tension, it should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still somewhat of a noob, but I have heard that your problem may be because the extruder is not getting the filament out fast enough. You are trying to extrude filament before it is sufficiently fluid. Try increasing your hotend temperature by 5 degrees.

Comment: your answer would have been my answer, as your understanding is correct and likely the correct answer to the question. If a 5° increase does not remove the problem, another 5° added until there is no clicking is the recommended approach.

Comment: I will try this and see if it helps, my hot end isn't cooling but it makes sense that maybe its not all fluid by time it comes out and is clogging it.

Comment: My settings are now a little insane but I have PLA printing at 190 mm/s at 237 on a mostly stock ender 3.

Comment: @TristanMaxson Obviously increasing the temperature helps on long straight segments, but on the slower parts of the print the extra temperature will reduce the quality of the print and also make bridges not bad, just impossible. It may be ok for specific prints.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely hitting the thermal limit of your hot end.

The standard Creality hotend used in your printers maxes out at around 8-12 mm³/s.
To calculate your current volumetric speed, you can simply calculate

`speed * layer height * extrusion width`

With an 0.45 mm extrusion width and 0.2 mm layer heights, printing at 130 mm/s would put you at around 11,7 mm³/s - very high for the standard hot end.

Increasing temperatures as suggested in the other answer will help, but might reduce print quality on other layers / intricate structures.

The "proper" solution would be a Volcano or SuperVolcano hot end, or any of the other "high flow" alternatives.